# How to change new instance tag Name when auto scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've created a new Alarm on my **AWS** account based on a Metric that I also have created.
I use this alarm to auto scale. When launching new instances I'm using `User Data` field to set up this new instance.
The only problem I'm facing is that I cannot modify the tags (specially the tag **Name**) of this new instance.
If I don't change that, all the new instances will have the same name which won't work with my current setup.

Is it possible to solve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up a new Name tag for the instance in its own user data script using AWS cli tools and the instance metadata. It would look like this:

```
aws ec2 create-tags \
  --resources $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) \
  --tag Key=Name,Value=MyNewNiceName \
  --region=us-east-1
```

See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-tags.html

Comment: Is it possible to auto increment the Name value? i.e.: MyNewNiceName1 then MyNewNiceName2, etc...

Comment: It is. You could have a "Count" tag, list all instances with that tag, get the higher and add 1. Or you could save this to a database and query. Or you could use the instance id instead...