# AWS AutoScaling Increment Name Tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I've created an AutoScaling group in AWS and I'd like to auto-increment the Name Tag so that my instances actually make sense in the console.

Example:

```
MyAwesomeWebApp - Scaling Group
Load Balancers - webapp
Desired - 1
Min - 1
Max - 5
..........
```

Instance Names Should be (Depending on scale myawesomewebapp1 will always be up but the rest don't have to be):

```
myawesomewebapp1
myawesomewebapp2
myawesomewebapp3
myawesomewebapp4
myawesomewebapp5
```

This was mentioned here but not answered fully:

[How to change new instance tag Name when auto scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307104/how-to-change-new-instance-tag-name-when-auto-scaling)

Comment: Can I ask why you would want to do this? One of the main reasons of using AutoScaling is to make your instance stateless (ie. all the same, if one dies, no data is lost & can be replaced seamlessly) and as a result it would be pointless to want to number each instance.

Comment: The application has a requirement that the host system have a hostname...it's still old-school

Comment: Ok. So what does a resource tag have to do with giving it a hostname? I think you need to give us more information about exactly what you're trying to do and why you're trying do it. This way, people can offer alternative and solutions and it will prevent you getting voted down with no answers :)

Comment: There is value to this when working with Windows on AWS...not common but it is a thing. A specific example would be managing the Windows hosts with Ansible. To use Kerberos authentication the host names need to match the dns/computer object names in AD and the easiest way to expose that data to Ansible is by the Name tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can't accomplish that in an autoscaling group configuration. However, with the API you could. When a new instance starts it could send an SNS notification that triggers (perhaps via an HTTP endpoint) an API call to set the instance's name tag based on some logic/counter combination.